# django slice numbers in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Is there a way to get multiple digits of a given number within a django template?

For example:

```
{{ some_num|get_digit:2 }}
```

will give you the second right most digit. For 1224531 it would be 3

Is there a way to get the last 3 digits or the first 5 digits? Like python's slicing?

something like:

```
{{ some_num|get_digits:2,5}}
```

Comment: searching for "django template tag slice" would have brought you to the answer!

Answer (score 42):

There is a the "slice" template tag

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

It uses the same syntax as Python's list slicing.

Example:

```
{{ some_list|slice:":2" }}
```

in python this is equivalent to:

```
some_list[:2]
```

BTW your 2nd example would be `"2:5"` not `"2,5"`

NB. Python slicing works on any 'sequence'. Strings and lists are sequences. Numbers are not!

Comment: but does this mean i'd have to convert the number to a list first?

Comment: @9-bits : the slice tag works like python's slice: a string is iterable, so it works perfectly on string. It does not work on numbers - but again, python's slice does not work on numbers either.

Comment: does not work on dynamic values - i.e. where index of slicing comes from a variable.

In Jinja2 templates you just do {{ some_list[:upper_index] }} and it works.

Comment: What would be the behavior in a for loop? For instance, looping posts from a model in |slice: 4 ? Always the first id will be displayed in this case? I am working in a issue where I need to loop four items and remove the first id or id=1 but it seen that based on id the loop is shuffled. So, the first id will always be retrieved?

Answer (score 6):

any extra filter that converts the number into a string before slicing will work. I used these variants:

```
{{ some_num|slugify|slice:"2:5" }}
```

and

```
{{ some_num|stringformat:"d"|slice:"5:10" }}
```

Answer (score 3):

`{{1234567|make_list|slice:'2:5'|join:''}}`

Stefano's answer is on the right track. You need a pre-processing step to turn your number into a list, and a post-processing step to merge that list back into string.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write code as follow for slicing :-
`{{valueformoney|slice:"0:4"}}`

```py
{% for cloth in valueformoney|slice:"0:4" %}
    <div class="product h-100  w-100 border rounded ">
        <div class="img__container">
            <img src="{{cloth.cloth_image.url}}" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product__bottom">
            <div class="price">
                <span class="text-danger"> <del>{% min_price cloth as result %} {{ result|rupee}}</del></span>&nbsp;
                <span>{% discount_price cloth as result %}{{result|rupee}}</span>
                <span class="float-right badge p-3 badge-info">Save {{cloth.cloth_discount}}% </span>
            </div>
            <h3 class="p-4">{{cloth.cloth_name}}</h3>
            <div class="button">
                <a href="/product_detail/{{cloth.cloth_slug}}" class="btn-block">See More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```